# How do I get a Realtek Wireless USB Airlink101 AWLL5088 working?

Tags: 11.10, wireless, realtek

I am running Ubuntu 11.10,  32bit. I ordered them a Realtek Airlink101 AWLL5088 based upon the relative ease for linux installation. I am having trouble installing the drivers.

I copied the drivers to /usr/src/ and ran

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

from that director listed above. I have tried ndiswrapper, and allowing the default drivers, but with no luck. It seems to continue to try and use the default free drivers, even though I have blacklisted them using the guide described [here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper)

There was no error, I was asked which card I was using. I looked at the packaging and at the support page, and guessed number 2, allowed to finish, and rebooted. It continued detect the wireless network after the reboot, but would never complete the connection.

I would appreciate any feedback. I am kind of stuck trying to figure this out.

Comment: What error message did you get when you ran `sudo ./install.sh` ? Have you rebooted ?

Comment: There was no error, I was asked which card I was using. I looked at the packaging and at the support page, and guessed number 2, allowed to finish, and rebooted. It continued detect the wireless network after the reboot, but would never complete the connection.

Answer (score 2):

Onieric Driver: [AWLL5088 Onieric 32/64bit v3.0.2590 Driver](http://q.gs/278189/googledoc)

Driver automatically updates for each kernel.
You have to install dkms and header packages, first.

(Be sure to substitute file name below with the version you downloaded.)

```
sudo apt-get install dkms linux-headers-generic 
tar xvf Airlink_AWLL5088_Onieric_Driver-v_3.1.2590.tar.gz

cd Airlink_AWLL5088_Onieric_Driver-v_3.1.2590/

./install-with-dkms.sh
```

To remove from dkms use:

```
./remove-from-dkms.sh
```

The install.sh script from "Realtek" still works but wont recompile automatically for each new kernel.

http://alienlinux.weebly.com/